# How to check the application compatibility

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

I just finished my application, using Visual Studio 2010. I have 2 folders, one is named `debug` and the second `release`. Both folders have a exe file and few odd files. Now I just placed this exe file to my second PC which is running Windows XP and the app is showing an error.

My second PC is running Windows 7 and there is not a problem.
I was thinking to run VirtualBox with Windows 7, but my RAM is just 2GB and its hard to do it.

Can I at least be sure that all the Windows 7 PCs can run it? As I said I have made an exe file as release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its better to create setup project in the same solution and then create a deployment package. It's main advantage is that it will automatically find all the dependencies in your project and by this I think you can overcome this problem

Comment: Worked. After creating the setup project I reallised that windows xp was missing .NET framework 4 :)